# Handle one-to-many relationships between business logic and data access layer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, architecture

I have the following **architecture**:

- *Business logic*: Business logic happens here. This layer deals with *data transform objects* only (= objects containing business related data, no technical data)
- *Data access layer*: Provides connection to the database. Accepts *data transform objects* and transforms them into *entity objects* (= objects containing database related information like technical ids). Returns *data transform objects*.
- Some other layers (not important)

Now I'm dealing with one-to-many relationships (example: an invoice can have multiple positions).

**Data transform objects**:

```
public class InvoiceDto
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public List<InvoicePositionDto> InvoicePositions { get; set; }
}

public class InvoicePositionDto
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Costs { get; set; }
}
```

**Entity objects**:

```
[Table("Invoices")]
public class InvoiceEntity : BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<InvoicePositionEntity> InvoicePositions { get; set; }
}

[Table("InvoicePosition")]
public class InvoicePositionEntity : BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Costs { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public virtual InvoiceEntity Invoice { get; set; }
}
```

---

When creating an invoice, I will just insert all positions on *data access layer*.

When updating an invoice, I have to consider the following cases regarding the positions of an invoice:

1. Nothing was changed
2. A new position was added
3. A position was deleted
4. An existing position was changed

How can I handle those cases? I guess I always have to "compare" the `InvoicePositionDtos` with the `InvoicePositionEntities` of the existing dataset. Is there an easier way?

Technical details - the following frameworks are used:

- Entity Framework
- AutoMapper

Comment: EntityFramework can handle all of these scenarios already.  You are essentially throwing that all out the window by layering DTOs that lose information on top of the entities (which, by the way, are basically DTOs already.)  Is it worth it? What are you gaining?

Comment: So your suggestion is to send the entites from Entity Framework from the bottom (data access layer) to the top (view)? I did this in the past project and encountered some problems having my view bound to a model from Entity Framework directly.

Comment: What kind of problems?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30068980/entity-framework-architecture-for-wpf-mvvm-applications - for example.

Comment: In short: I made good experience with your suggestion in a web environment. I tried it in a desktop environment. I've bound the entity from entity framework to the view directly. When the user changes values in the view, they are reflected by entity framework automatically. This is where things start to get ugly. To avoid this, I had to detach and copy entities from entity framework ...

Comment: Ok.  At any rate, even with a strict separation, you can "re-attach" your uppper-layer DTOs to the lower-layer entities so long as you are keeping track of the primary keys.  You ought to then still be able to use the ORM layer to manage the CRUD tracking.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try something like the following?

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<InvoiceDto, InvoiceEntity>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.InvoicePositions, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.InvoicePositions.Select(x => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<InvoiceEntity>(x)).ToList()));
```